# Change Ruby Logger output dynamically

Tags: ruby, logging

I'd like to change dynamically the output used by the Logger.

in the lib:

```
@log = Logger.new(p, 10, 1024000)
```

in the main class:

```
mylib_instance.log.set_log(STDOUT) # something like that, but this does not work
```

Mickael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know you can't do this with standart Logger, but you can find this in [Log4r logger](http://log4r.sourceforge.net/rdoc/classes/Log4r/Logger.html#M000064)